# Remove pixmap PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How do you clear a pixmap from a label in PyQt.

Currently I have this:

```
self.ui.clan_shield_0.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.)
```

I have no idea what function to call to remove the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass it a null QPixmap:

```py
self.ui.clan_shield_0.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
```

Or better use clear() method:

```
self.ui.clan_shield_0.clear()
```

Comment: null QPixmap hides the text. Clear removes the text.